# Adding a class to html element conditionally with grails tags

Tags: grails, gsp

With tags, you can do this in a gsp:

```
<g:if test="${someBean?.aCondition}">
  <div class="aSection">
  ...
  </div>
</g:if>
```

What I really want to do is add a second 'class' that either contains the 'display:none' or 'display:block' attributes based the value of '${someBean?.aCondition}'.

The final html would like this:

```
<div class="aSection hiddenItem">
...
</div>
```

(the div would have 'shownItem' for its class if ${someBean?.aCondition} is true)

The corresponding css:

```
.shownItem
{
  display: block;
}
.hiddenItem
{
  display: none;
}
```

What's a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
<div class="aSection ${someBean?.aCondition ? 'shownItem':'hiddenItem'}">
...
</div>
```

You can use ${} blocks inside html attributes, no problem, just be sure not to use any double-quotes in your expression block, as that confuses things.

Comment: how to add multiple conditions to this .. is it possible

Comment: @Norman  that's a groovy code block in the ${}, so ya, you could do:  ${ (someBean.value2 == 2 && someBean.value3 == 3) ? 'shownItem' : 'hiddenItem' }, but it's getting messy.  Perhaps you can do that logic in the controller, and pass the result into the GSP using the model?

Comment: for every condition I want to show different class not exactly only between two option can that be done ?

Answer (score 6):

Or if you don't want the attribute displayed at all on some (say for an autofocus tag) condition:

```
<input name="email" type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email" ${!flash.email ? 'autofocus="autofocus"':''} value="${flash.email}">
```

Comment: can we use multiple conditions for this